# Take pictures automatically from mobile camera and use it as a web cam

Tags: 18.04, python, webcam, python-2.7, camera

I have found a python script which can automatically capture my photo through web cam. My web cam quality is far inferior and I need superior quality photo because I wanna use that for image recognition.Now my concern is Can't I just change the web cam settings where instead of default webcam usage,I can make use of IP webcam ?
My code which automatically captures photo using open cv.

```
from cv2 import * 
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
xx=1 //capture just one picture as soon as web cam gets opened
while xx<2:
  ret, img = cam.read()
  cv2.imshow('img',img)
  value=random.randint(1,10000)
  cv2.imwrite("/home/mukesh/Desktop/recognition/recognition/unknown_pictures/filename"+str(value)+".jpg",img)
  xx+=1
  k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
  if k == 27:
    break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If I am using IP webcam right now, I have to manually enter the port address in the browser and I need to manually save the photo as well. Plus no green light at the top of the web cam shows up. I want to change it to ipwebcam instead of default. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have droidcam as well but it's lagging compared to IP webcam.